# Process disturbance in PI controller help

Tags: pid-control, matlab, process-engineering, simulink

This is the project i'm working on and i'm struggling to understand one sentence which is stopping me from progressing the project.
[image]

[image]

I'm struggling to understand what it means when it says to add +/- 80% step changes in Qh to represent process disturbances.

Comment: I guess it means make a step change from $Q_h$ to $1.8Q_h$ or $0.2Q_h$ and show what the controller does.

Comment: Without reading everything, my take is if the process deviates +/- some level of steady state, you are only to correct it by +/- 80% of that deviation. Example, If Qh increases my +80 flow units, then maintain H2 by increasing Qc by, 80% * Qc, flow units (or perhaps by 64 (80% * 80) flow units).